# How to build custom Cyanogenmod for Galaxy S5 Exynos (G900H)?

Tags: android, build, galaxy, cyanogenmod, custom-rom

I am trying to build my own custom Cyanogenmod ROM for Galaxy S5 **Exynos (G900H)**, but it seems that this model was never supported by CM and now by LineageOS.

At first I tried to flash the regular Galaxy S5 (klte) ROM, however the regular system.img and recovery.img didn't work at all on my specific special model (Exynos) obviously, but I had to try.

I saw a few unofficial ROMs for that model over the internet but I need the **source code** for them (in order to edit it by myslef) and some explanation for how to combine the new Exynos code with the original CM (or LineageOS) repository.

So, is there any way to build a CM ROM for Galaxy S5 Exynos (G900H)?

Comment: Have you tried it here?
https://forum.xda-developers.com/
Maybe this is a better forum for your request

Comment: Yes I have, but no answers there yet.

Comment: What about this?
https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/galaxy-s-5-android-development-exynos/rom-lineageos-14-1-t3612300

it's an unofficial LineageOS 14.1 Version, maybe you find here some usefull information.

Comment: That's for G903F, I need for G900H

Comment: Sorry didn't saw that, look here:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/galaxy-s-5-android-development-exynos/rom-lineageos-14-1-g900h-t3529334

maybe you could help him/them

Comment: I emailed him and sent him a message in xda. Meanwhile I am using their sources but it has a lot of build errors.. so I'm waiting for someone who had built a ROM for G900H already.